# Error : Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application

Tags: android

I'm trying to add a viewgroup class to windowmanager but get this error

```
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.amadey.final_version/com.example.amadey.final_version.LockActivity}: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
```

And this is my code:

```
WindowManager manager = ((WindowManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE));
        WindowManager.LayoutParams localLayoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
        localLayoutParams.width = 100;
        localLayoutParams.height = 100;
        localLayoutParams.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_BASE_APPLICATION;
        customViewGroup view = new customViewGroup(this);
        manager.addView(view, localLayoutParams);
```

What do I do wrong?And how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting the `WindowManager` in the activity, then directly use `getSystemService()`, don't use `getApplicationContext`.

Comment: Well, now I don't have it but I don't have my window either.Can you help me with it?

Comment: Where are you accessing the window service?

Comment: In activity, but in service I still do have this error

Comment: Are you still getting the token null error after using `getSystemService()` method in your Service?

Comment: Sorry for so long response. Here's how I get system service : WindowManager manager = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE));

Comment: I just checked you also have to add `localLayoutParams.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE` to your layout params

Comment: Can I use another type of window, which can be closed by pressing on home or back button?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110755/discussion-between-rick-sanchez-and-s-drumble4).